# Is, I am happy to talk more tomorrow, grammatically correct

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, past-tense, future

Is this grammatically correct?

> Thanks Bob, I am happy to talk more tomorrow.

Or is it better to say:

> Thanks Bob, I **will be** happy to talk more tomorrow.

Does present and future tense matter? What is the correct way of wording this?

Comment: They're both fine. It's just an arbitrary choice on the part of the speaker, who may be thinking in terms of his current or future feelings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Bob, I’d be happy to talk with you more tomorrow.